# Cordova Hybrid Apps

Tags: cordova, ipados

Does [Cordova Hybrid Apps](https://cordova.apache.org) work on iPadOS or is [iOS Platform](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/index.html) enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it ll work, ipadOS is like ios with more features.

**Sources :**

https://twitter.com/jcesarmobile/status/1135975882332487681

https://github.com/apache/cordova/issues/118